# How is it possible to override a property with a new type?

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism

I don't understand how this compiles and works perfectly :|

Since when is it possible to change the type of a property (from `Nullable<bool>` to `bool` and from `int` to `Nullable<int>`) when overriding it?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testBase = new BaseClass();
        var testDerived = new DerivedClass();

        Console.WriteLine("'" + Convert.ToString(testBase.BaseInt) + "'");
        Console.WriteLine("'" + Convert.ToString(testDerived.BaseInt) + "'");

        Console.WriteLine("'" + Convert.ToString(testBase.BaseBoolNullable) + "'");
        Console.WriteLine("'" + Convert.ToString(testDerived.BaseBoolNullable) + "'");
    }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public bool? BaseBoolNullable { get; set; }
    public int BaseInt { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public new bool BaseBoolNullable { get; set; }
    public new int? BaseInt { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
'0'
''
''
'False'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't [overridden](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual) the base properties though, just [hidden](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier) them.

If you change `DerivedClass` like so, to access the base class's properties, you'll see that they're still available.

```
public new bool BaseBoolNullable
{
    get { return base.BaseBoolNullable ?? false; }
    set { base.BaseBoolNullable = value; }
}
public new int? BaseInt
{
    get { return base.BaseInt; }
    set { base.BaseInt = value ?? 0; }
}
```

If you used `virtual` and `override` then you'd see that, as you expected, you can't actually override a property with a different type.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual bool? BaseBoolNullable { get; set; }
    public virtual int BaseInt { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override bool BaseBoolNullable { get; set; }
    public override int? BaseInt { get; set; }
}
```

> 'DerivedClass.BaseBoolNullable': type must be 'bool?' to match overridden member 'BaseClass.BaseBoolNullable'
>
> 'DerivedClass.BaseInt': type must be 'int' to match overridden member 'BaseClass.BaseInt'

Comment: Is it a big code smell to write such code as in my question? Like morally wrong or something

Comment: your second example won't compile, right?

Comment: @ibiza I'd say it's a *pretty big indication* of a code smell. There *are* uses for hiding members, but it's almost always a bad idea